# Javascript - hiding table rows based on enclosed TD content

Tags: javascript, html-table

I'm writing a python app which is displaying an HTML table of pupil capabilities.  I want to add the ability to filter the view depending on those capabilities - including multiple filters at the same time, hence wanting to do this in javascript (managing this via database lookups was becoming unwieldy).

I have a table which has a grid of capabilities (true/false), and to each 'false' I have added a class, such as 'pupil_web', and I have written a javascript function which will hide the  on that row, triggered by a button at the top of each column.

But what I want is for the function to hide the **entire row** if it contains a td of that class, and I can't work out how to do it.  I'm a fairly basic Python programmer, and this is my first project of any reasonable size; so far it's going well, but having spent a couple of hours trying to get this working (and getting as far as hiding the TD, not the enclosing row), I'd appreciate some help or a pointer in the right direction - I can't work out how to make the function look inside the row's content, only to look at each individual TD.

Here's the Javascript (note that at the moment I'm using Jinja2 to create multiple functions, each one for each capability, where the name of the function and the capability DIV content are linked - again I'm sure I'm not doing that in the best manner (creating a function for each column), but at the moment I'd rather get it working in the present form and then hopefully optimise in the future).

```
function toggle_{{ capability }}() {

        var table, td, i;
        table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        td = table.getElementsByClassName("div_{{ capability }}");

        // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
          for (i = 0; i < td.length; i++) {
            if (td[i].style.display === "none") {
                td[i].style.display = "";
              } else {
                td[i].style.display = "none";
              }
            }
          }
```

Here's a simple version of the HTML table (the real one has about 20 columns, with a class tag present for the column entry that would lead to a row being hidden).

```
<tr>
    <td>
        Pupil 1
    </td>
    <td>
        <img class="pupil_web" src="static/cross.png" width="25">
    </td>
    <td>
        <img src="static/tick.png" width="25">    
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Pupil 2
    </td>
    <td>
        <img src="/static/tick.png" width="25">
    </td>
    <td>
        <img class="pupil_email" src="static/cross.png" width="25">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated - I've not been at this long (I'm about 4 months in to a 2-year self-study plan), but I'm trying to learn rather than just give up and/or paste code in without understanding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function toggle_{{ capability }}() {
  var table, td, i;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  td = table.getElementsByClassName("div_{{ capability }}");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  if (td.parent().style.display === "none") {
    td.parent().style.display = "";
  } else {
    td.parent().style.display = "none";
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks - just tried that, it didn't work nor did `td[i].parent().style.display`, but that led me to try the following.
`for (i = 0; i < td.length; i++) {
                if (td[i].parentElement.style.display === "none") {
                    td[i].parentElement.style.display = "";
                  } else {
                    td[i].parentElement.style.display = "none";
                  }
                }
              }`
Which hides the elements and moves everything in the table to 'fill' the gap left by the hidden ones - getting closer, but still not there..

Comment: .. but using `td[i].parentElement.parentElement.style.display` did work as I wanted - thanks @nimrod-p